# Tensorflow Sampled Softmax Loss Correct Usage

Tags: python, tensorflow

In a classification problem with many classes, tensorflow docs suggests using [sampled_softmax_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss) over a simple [softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) to reduce training runtime.

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss) and [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cd2789e5e771fd01fa4bc3f00ae93f089ed30b65/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py) (line 1180), the call pattern for sampled_softmax_loss is:

```py
tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights, # Shape (num_classes, dim)     - floatXX
                     biases,        # Shape (num_classes)          - floatXX 
                     labels,        # Shape (batch_size, num_true) - int64
                     inputs,        # Shape (batch_size, dim)      - floatXX  
                     num_sampled,   # - int
                     num_classes,   # - int
                     num_true=1,  
                     sampled_values=None,
                     remove_accidental_hits=True,
                     partition_strategy="mod",
                     name="sampled_softmax_loss")
```

It's unclear (at least to me) how to convert a real world problem into the shapes that this loss function requires. I think the 'inputs' field is the problem.

Here is a copy-paste-ready minimum working example that throws a matrix multiplication shape error when calling the loss function.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256  # 1st layer number of features
n_input = 784     # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10    # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)    

# Dependent & Independent Variable Placeholders
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes]) # 

# Weights and Biases
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Super simple model builder
def tiny_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer   

# Create the model
pred = tiny_perceptron(x, weights, biases)    

# Set up loss function inputs and inspect their shapes
w = tf.transpose(weights['out'])
b = biases['out']
labels = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y, 1), [-1,1])
inputs = pred
num_sampled = 3
num_true = 1
num_classes = n_classes

print('Shapes\n------\nw:\t%s\nb:\t%s\nlabels:\t%s\ninputs:\t%s' % (w.shape, b.shape, labels.shape, inputs.shape))
# Shapes
# ------
# w:      (10, 256)  # Requires (num_classes, dim)     - CORRECT
# b:      (10,)      # Requires (num_classes)          - CORRECT
# labels: (?, 1)     # Requires (batch_size, num_true) - CORRECT
# inputs: (?, 10)    # Requires (batch_size, dim)      - Not sure

loss_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                     weights=w,
                     biases=b,
                     labels=labels,
                     inputs=inputs,
                     num_sampled=num_sampled,
                     num_true=num_true,
                     num_classes=num_classes))
```

The final line triggers and ValueError, stating that you cant multiply tensors with shape (?,10) and (?,256). As a general rule, I'd agree with that statement. Full error shown below:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 256 for 'sampled_softmax_loss_2/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,10], [?,256].
```

If the 'dim' value from tensorflow docs is intended to be constant, either the 'weights' or 'inputs' variables going into the loss function are incorrect.

Any thoughts would be awesome, I'm totally stumped on how to use this loss function correctly & it would have a huge impact on training time for the model we're using it for (500k classes). Thanks!

**---EDIT---**

It is possible to get the sample shown above to run without errors by playing with parameters and ignoring the `sampled_softmax_loss` call pattern's expected inputs. If you do that, it results in a trainable model that has 0 impact on prediction accuracy (as you would expect).

Comment: I could be wrong, but try defining your weights with shape `[num_hidden_1, num_input]`, and `[num_classes, num_hidden_1]`. It certainly seems like your data is not being transformed as expected by your fully connected layers...

Comment: @Engineero thanks for weighing in. The hidden weights among consecutive layers of the model are multiplied together so that would be (256, 784) and (10, 256) which is not compatible. 

To make sure the rest of the code is correct setting `n_hidden_1` to 10 (same as `n_classes`)  will succeed. Of course, that doesn't do anything productive since it optimizes on the wrong criteria! Just a little test.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking in terms of the operations: `h = W1 * x`, `y = W2 * h`, in which case you would need your weight matrices with the dimensions suggested. I guess it implements the reverse: `h = x * W1` and `y = h * W2`. **Edit:** now I see where you actually define your network. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your softmax layer you are multiplying your network predictions, which have dimension `(num_classes,)` by your `w` matrix which has dimension `(num_classes, num_hidden_1)`, so you end up trying to compare your target labels of size `(num_classes,)` to something that is now size `(num_hidden_1,)`. Change your tiny perceptron to output `layer_1` instead, then change the definition of your cost. The code below might do the trick.

```py
def tiny_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    return layer_1

layer_1 = tiny_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
loss_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                     weights=weights['h1'],
                     biases=biases['b1'],
                     labels=labels,
                     inputs=layer_1,
                     num_sampled=num_sampled,
                     num_true=num_true,
                     num_classes=num_classes))
```

When you train your network with some optimizer, you will tell it to minimize `loss_function`, which should mean that it will adjust both sets of weights and biases.

Comment: If you change that solution so the last line uses `weights['h1']` and `biases['b1']` rather than `weights['out]` and `biases['out']` it will pass the build step & will even execute. But, according to the docs, the value for weights should be `(num_classes, dim)` which would be `(10, ?)`. 

You can confirm that something is not quite right by training a complete model. The loss will decrease nicely but accuracy is random or worse than random.

I'll update the post to include the full training code to illustrate

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I will try to look at it some more, but the dimensions in this case don't make sense to me. It seems like I answered prematurely...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The piece I didn't understand was that sampled_softmax rips off the final softmax layer and substitutes it within the loss function.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is to pass right shape of weight, bias, input and label. The shape of weight passed to sampled_softmax is not the the same with the general situation.
For example, `logits = xw + b`, call sampled_softmax like this:
`sampled_softmax(weight=tf.transpose(w), bias=b, inputs=x)`, NOT `sampled_softmax(weight=w, bias=b, inputs=logits)`!!
Besides, label is not one-hot representation. if your labels are one-hot represented, pass `labels=tf.reshape(tf.argmax(labels_one_hot, 1), [-1,1])`