# Pairwise comparisons for model training/testing - how to parameter tune?

Tags: python, random-forest, xgboost, modeling

For some reasons, I have base dataframes of the following structure

```
print(df1.shape)
display(df1.head())
print(df2.shape)
display(df2.head())
```

[image]

Where the top dataframe is my features set and my bottom is the output set. To turn this into a problem that is amenable to data modeling I first do:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df1, df2, train_size = 0.8)
```

I then have a split for 80% training and 20% testing.

Since the output set (df2; y_test/y_train) is individual measurements with no inherent meaning on their own, I calculate pairwise distances between the labels to generate a single output value denoting the pairwise distances between observations using (the distances are computed after z-scoring; the z-scoring code isn't described here but it is done):

```
y_train = pdist(y_train, 'euclidean')
y_test = pdist(y_test, 'euclidean')
```

Similarly I then apply this strategy to the features set to generate pairwise distances between individual observations of each of the instances of each feature.

```
def feature_distances(input_vector):
    modified_vector = np.array(input_vector).reshape(-1,1)
    vector_distances = pdist(modified_vector, 'euclidean')
    vector_distances = pd.Series(vector_distances)
    return vector_distances

x_train = x_train.apply(feature_distances, axis = 0)
x_test = x_test.apply(feature_distances, axis = 0)
```

I then proceed to train & test all of my models.
For now I am trying linear regression , random forest, xgboost.

Is there any easy way to implement a cross validation scheme in my dataset?
Since my problem requires calculating pairwise distances between observations, I am struggling to identify an easy way to do cross validation schemes to optimize parameter tuning.

GridsearchCV doesn't quite work here since in each instance of the test/train split, distances have to be recomputed to avoid contamination of test with train.

Hope it's clear!

Answer (score 0):

```py
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=n)
```

here `X` is independent feature, `y` is dependent feature means what you actually want to predict - it could be label or continuous value. We used `train_test_split` on train dataset and we are using (`x_train`, `y_train`) to train model and (`x_test`, `y_test`) to test model to ensure performance of model on unknown data(`x_test`, `y_test`). In your case you have given y as df2 which is wrong just figure out your target feature and give it as y and there is no need to split test data.

Comment: I think you misread my question. The splitting is before the the Y values are calculated by euclidean distance which returns a single value. The splitting must be done before single value distance calculation to minimize contamination of test by the train. Doing the split earlier just makes it easier to make sure the data is split identically in the features and outcomes set.

Answer (score 0):

First, what I understood from the shape of your data frames that you have 42 samples and 1643 features in the input, and each output vector consists of 392 values.

**Huge Input:** In case, you are sure that your problem has 1643 features, you might need to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality instead of pairwise distance. You should collect more samples instead of 42 samples to avoid overfitting because it is not enough data to train and test your model.

**Huge Output**: you could use sampled_softmax_loss to speed up the training process as mentioned in [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss) . You could also read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43810195/16310106). In case, you do not want to follow this approach, you can continue training with this output but it takes some time.